# Two arrays to one

Tags: php

I have two arrays and I want one, can I add array 2 to array one?

```
$array1 = array("Germany" => 2, "Belgium"=> 3);
$array2 = array("France" => 4, "Italy"=> 5);

$final_array = {both arrays in one};
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the `array_merge` function, like this:

```
$final_array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($final_array);
```

When I run the above script it'll output:

```
Array (
    [Germany] => 2
    [Belgium] => 3 
    [France] => 4
    [Italy] => 5
)
```

Take a quick read here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge` like

```
$final_arr = array_merge($array1 , $array2);
print_r($final_arr);
```

See this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for more

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention that on duplicated keys array_merge() returns the value from the second array. So, if you have different values with same keys - you should write your own function.
For example:

```
    <?php

$a = array('rund' => '2', 'group' => '3', 'kupon' => 'utre', 'tralala' => 'shtur_kupon');
$b = array('grund' => '2', 'group' => 'ww', 'soup' => '1', 'tralala' => 'fd');

function two_arrays_merge_all_values(array $a, array $b) {
    foreach ($b as $b_key => $b_value) {
        $a_last_index = count($a);
        $current_index = 1;
        foreach ($a as $a_key => $a_value) {
            if ($a_key === $b_key) {
                $unique = uniqid();
                $a[$b_key . '_' . $unique] = $b[$b_key];
                unset($b[$b_key]);
                break;
            }
            if ($current_index == $a_last_index) {
                $a[$b_key] = $b[$b_key];
                unset($b[$b_key]);
            }
            $current_index++;
        }
    }

    return $a;
}
```

Comment: You can find the source here too: [GitHub Gist link](https://gist.github.com/koredalin/ea9e94041335b3e46ad1)